# Bind a TreeView to HierarchicalDataTemplate and DataTemplate where DataType is an Interface

Tags: c#, wpf, interface, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I've got a complex question I've been working on for a good week now trying to work correctly. I am using WPF .NET 4.5, the MVVM pattern, and Prism. I want to display a TreeView that binds to an `ObservableCollection<IScript> LoadedScripts`:

```
namespace Library.Data.Scripting    
{
    public interface IScript : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        ...

        IScriptDescription ScriptDescription { get; }

        ...
    }


    public interface IScriptDescription : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        ...

        string Name { get; }
        IEnumerable<ISectionDescription> Sections { get; }
        ScriptStatus Status { get; }

        ...
    }

    public interface ISectionDescription : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        ...

        string Name { get; }
        ScriptStatus Status { get; }

        ...
    }
}
```

I want the TreeView to display the list of scripts and each script to have children for the script's sections. For each node that is visible, I want to show the Name and Status. That is, for each `IScript` in `LoadedScripts` show a textbox of `ScriptDescription.Name` and `ScriptDescription.Status`. For each child `ISectionDescription`, a TextBox containing `ISectionDescription.Name` and `ISectionDescription.Status`.

This is all fairly straightforward, except for the fact that I'm binding to Interfaces. I found how I'm supposed to be able to overcome this, using a `DataTemplateSelector`, but my treeview isn't displaying the text correctly in my templates. Instead, I am getting the `object.ToString()` for the `IScript`s in my `ObservableCollection<IScript> LoadedScripts` with no children. I'm not getting any kind of errors or warnings in the `Output` window either.

I feel like I am really close but I can't get it to correctly display my data. I have verified I am indeed getting my data and if I put a basic `DataTemplate` for `TreeView.ItemTemplate` I am able to display the top-level `IScript` nodes. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any input is much appreciated!

Here's my DataTemplateSelector:

```
namespace Library.App.GUI
{
    public class ScriptDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {

        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {

            FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

            if (element != null && item != null && item is IScript)
            {
                return element.FindResource("ScriptTemplate") as HierarchicalDataTemplate;
            }

            else if (element != null && item != null && item is ISectionDescription)
            {
                return element.FindResource("SectionTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
namespace Library.App.GUI
{
    public class TestStatusViewModel
    {
        private IScriptManager ScriptManager;

        public ObservableCollection<IScript> LoadedScripts
        {
            get 
            { 
                return ScriptManager.LoadedScripts; 
            }
        }

        public TestStatusViewModel()
        {
            //Locate the ScriptManager in the MEF container using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator
            ScriptManager = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IScriptManager>();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Library.App.GUI.TestStatusView"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Library.App.GUI"
            xmlns:script="clr-namespace:Library.Data.Scripting;assembly=MTFCommon"
            xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Prism;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism"
            xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
            mc:Ignorable="d" 
            d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="200">


    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:ScriptDataTemplateSelector x:Key="ScriptTemplateSelector"/>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate  x:Key="ScriptTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding ScriptDescription.Sections}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" TextAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding ScriptDescription.Name}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Right" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding ScriptDescription.Status}" />
            </Grid>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="SectionTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" TextAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Right" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding Status}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <ItemsControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TreeView Name="treeView" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ScriptTemplateSelector}" ItemsSource="{Binding LoadedScripts}" />
    </ItemsControl>

</UserControl>
```

P.S.: Everything in the Library.Data namespace I am not able to personally edit since it is an external library. I can put in a request to have it changed if that must happen, but prefer not.

P.P.S.: This is my first SO question, please let me know if I missed any important information. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `DataTemplateSelector` not working, you might want to check to see if `element.FindResource` is returning anything. If it returns null (or your `as` returns null), then the `ToString` will be used to display the items in the tree.

Comment: I've put breakpoints inside my `DataTemplateSelector` and see it fire the correct number of times for how many `IScript`s are in the collection, and it's returning a `DataTemplate` object. Yet it's behaving like it's not actually using the `DataTemplate` that is being returned.

Comment: I just threw a quick test app together, and copied & pasted your code (obviously with stubs for the scripts). It works like a champ. What version of .NET are you running? I tested with all targets available to my in VS2012 (I have 4.5 installed and all service packs). Are you getting any Binding errors in your output window?

Comment: I'm running .NET 4.5 VS2012 as well. I just realized I am indeed getting the children as well, but still just the `Library.Script` and `Library.SectionDescription` instead of the actual data. I think I may have a problem with the bindings or something. Though, if I put in a textbox with the text statically set to "foobar" I still get the same result. *shrug*

Comment: So, setting the `TextBox.Text="foobar"` will show a type name in the output? You might want to create a simple sample app to make sure that you aren't setting the `ItemTemplate` or `ItemTemplateSelector` somewhere.

Comment: I **am** setting the `ItemTemplateSelector` in my `TreeView` to the `DataTemplateSelector` I defined.

Comment: I meant that there could be some code that is replacing the templates. Obviously your selector is being used, but your templates aren't. If you can't see "foobar" in the text box, that template is obviously not being applied. And you said that your template selector is returning the template. I can see no other reason why it wouldn't work.